# Ruby-on-Rails display issue - May 2018 only exists once but my app is showing it 7 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I'm a beginner to coding. Apologies if this is some simple answer, but I've been looking for a couple hours and no luck.

Current problem: May 2018 exists with 1 run.

On my /months index page, there is a link to the **May 2018** page, where I could create my future runs this month.

However, if I create a 2nd run, when I navigate back to my /months index page, **TWO links** to May 2018 show up (not one like I expect).
In the db there is only one object May 2018, and it owns both runs. (It then becomes 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. links when I create more runs...)

Quick summary: This is a running-log app. A month has_many runs.
When I create a run, it's attached to a month.
      `runs_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    @run = @month.runs.build(run_params)
    @run[:user_id] = current_user.id
    @run[:pace_per_mile] = @run.format_pace_per_mile
    if @run.save
      redirect_to month_path(@month)
    else
      @month = Month.find(params[:month_id])
      @runs = @month.runs
      render 'months/show'
    end
  end
```

Here is my /month index.html.erb code where the error is happening:

```
<strong><h2>Your Previous Runs</h2></strong>
<% @months.each do |month| %>
  <%= link_to(month) do %>
    <h3><%= month.name %> <%= month.year %></h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my months#index so you can see the scope.

```
def index
  @months = current_user.months
  @month = Month.new
end
```

I can provide more code if I'm not including something!

@xploshioOn, @fool-dev, and @moveson, Thanks for your responses.

I'm including the month and user models, as well as the code where a month gets created...

month.rb

```
class Month < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :runs
  has_many :users, through: :runs

  validates :name, :year, presence: true

  def month_mileage
    self.runs.collect {|run| run.distance}.sum
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true

  has_many :runs
  has_many :months, through: :runs
end
```

I'm currently creating months from the **months_controller**. I'm starting to get the feeling this is where my error lies?

```
  def create
    @month = Month.new(month_params)
    if @month.save
      redirect_to month_url(@month)
    else
      @months = current_user.months
      render :index
    end
  end
```

Thanks again for any advice!

Comment: add the models of user and month please.

Comment: The code seems to be ok, I think the issue is on the model like `relationships`, could you please show the models with the relationship

Comment: @xploshioOn, fool-dev and moveson, I've added more snippets, as you asked. Thanks for your time. As I'm looking at the code, I think the problem might be my relationships? That months and users are only related through the join table (runs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be confusing to have the relationship with a User having many months through runs. Consider whether that relationship is necessary at all.

If you want to keep your current has many through relationship between User and Month, in your MonthsController#index action, you can do this:

```
def index
  @months = current_user.months.uniq
  @month = Month.new
end
```

If you want to do away with that relationship, in your MonthsController#index action, I would do this:

```
def index
  @months = current_user.runs.map(&:month).uniq
  @month = Month.new
end
```

Accessing months through current_user.runs is more explicit and may be easier to follow. Calling `.uniq` on the result will eliminate duplicates.

Keep in mind that both of the above options will result in your getting back an Array rather than an ActiveRecord object. To avoid this problem, you could run your query directly on the Month model:

```
def index
  @months = Month.joins(runs: :user).where(users: {id: current_user}).distinct
  @month = Month.new
end
```

This will return an ActiveRecord object allowing you to further refine your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help and very thorough reply @moveson! Will take all this under consideration. Yeah, the relationships as I've set them do seem problematic. I'll tinker with them a bit more, but returning an AR object does seem preferable. I can't upvote anything yet, but when I get enough cred, I'll come back to do so. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are loading an association and it takes the month for every item that is in the relationship. So just add .uniq to your query.

@months = current_user.months.uniq

Comment: Thanks for the help! In the end it did turn out to be a simple fix.  .uniq ! Would've taken me hours (years? haha) to think of this.

Comment: Yes it was. But don't worry, those are simple details that you will be learning on the road.